# simpleSAMLphp for single sign on using ADFS [Authenticate user from outside the ADFS domain]

Tags: adfs, simplesamlphp

I have a web application that uses SimpleSAMLphp for single sign on using ADFS to authenticate users inside a company.

When a user needs to access the web app from within the company (under the federation server domain), it is automatically authenticated and redirected to his main dashboard inside the web app. So till now, all works very good and the user is correctly bypassed the web app main Login page when he is in the company.

I'm facing a problem: when a user needs to access the web app from outside the company (not under the federation server domain), I need to automatically redirect him to the main Login page of the web app (to enter his username and password), and not to the federation service URL. Because if he tries to access the web app from outside the company, he receives an error (page cannot be displayed or not found) after the SimpleSAMLphp redirects him to the federation service URL which is not publicly accessible.

Maybe I'm missing some simpleSAMLphp configuration or others.
Can any one help me out in this issue.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't seems as SSP issue, however more information would be appreciated.

Is your internal web app user is trying to access publicly hosted to internet?

From what you describe, it seems that your site is internal site and won't be available outside of your network. You would need some kind of VPN access to be able to view it from outside of company network/building.